# LDAP Spring Security Authentication Error: code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310021B, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ldap

I am trying to authenticate a user (in Active Directory) from a user login page. Authentication code below failed with error code code 32 - 0000208D

Attached is exception thrown by Spring: LdapTemplate.java, search(...) method
(LDAP error code 32 - 0000208D)
https://app.box.com/s/t91jdn5gbf996v5e7bv75xpzwfttvizr

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);
    @Autowired
    private LdapProperties lProps;

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        String bUrl=lProps.getBellUrl();
        String bPort=String.valueOf(lProps.getBellPort());
        String bSrvName=lProps.getBellSrvName();
        String bMgrDn=lProps.getBellMgrDn();
        
        String contextSource=bUrl + ":" + bPort;
        String managerDn="CN=" + bSrvName + "," + bMgrDn;
        String bSrvPassword=lProps.getBellSrvPassword();
        String bSearchBase=lProps.getBellSearchBase();
        
        auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .contextSource().url(contextSource)
            .managerDn(managerDn)
            .managerPassword(bSrvPassword)
            .and()
            .userSearchBase(bSearchBase)
            .userSearchFilter("(sAMAccountName={0})");
    }
    .....
}
```

Errors:

```
2020-12-23 10:55:05,316 DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter [http-nio-8079-exec-1] Cleared SecurityContextHolder to complete request
2020-12-23 10:55:05,317 ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] [http-nio-8079-exec-1] Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-0310021B, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of: '' ]; remaining name '' 
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:183) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:197) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:223) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:203) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:197) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.4.2.jar:5.4.2]
```

Comment: Attached is exception thrown by Spring LdapTemplate.java, search(...) method
https://app.box.com/s/t91jdn5gbf996v5e7bv75xpzwfttvizr

Comment: Attached is exception thrown by Spring: LdapTemplate.java, search(...) method
(LDAP error code 32 - 0000208D)
https://app.box.com/s/t91jdn5gbf996v5e7bv75xpzwfttvizr